# How to use Robot Framework with Java using Eclipse as IDE

Tags: java, eclipse, robotframework

I have installed Robot Framework-EclipseIDE plugin by following the instruction on the following URL:

https://github.com/NitorCreations/RobotFramework-EclipseIDE/wiki/Installation

Installation is done successfully. Now I want to write some Test Cases using Java in Robot Framework. I am very novice in Robot Framework and I don't know how to start writing TCs in Robot Framework using Java in Eclipse.

Please help me to start.

Comment: https://github.com/NitorCreations/RobotFramework-EclipseIDE/wiki/Usage ?

Comment: Thanks for your quick comments. The above link is helpful for using/opening file in Robot Framework. I need the help for writing test case in Robot Framework as well as coding infrastructure.

Answer (score 4):

You don't write [Robot Framework](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/) test cases in Java unless you plan to extend RF with your own keyword libraries. Robot Framework tests are usually written in [text, html, TSV or reStructured](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.1#test-data-syntax) format. In text format the separator is important, usually **two spaces** or the pipe character.

The [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.googlecode.com/hg/doc/userguide/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html?r=2.8.1) is an excellent source of wisdom, but [this guide](http://www.virtuousprogrammer.com/?p=264) is good one for a quick introduction.

Robot Framework also has a [Quick Start Guide](https://code.google.com/p/robotframework/wiki/QuickStartGuide) which you can download.

I suggest that you start by simply starting a browser and using it to navigate to eg. search engine home page to perform a search. See [Selenium Library docs](http://robotframework-seleniumlibrary.googlecode.com/hg/doc/SeleniumLibrary.html?r=2.9.1) for more info.

Below is an example test case.

```
Search with DuckDuckGo
  Open Browser  https://duckduckgo.com/
  Input Text  search_form_input_homepage  ATDD
  Submit Form  search_form_homepage
  Page Should Contain  Using Robot Framework for ATDD
```

Comment: Just about everyone will need to write their own keyword libraries.